# Importing data from a VERY large text file into JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am making an application which deals with very large amounts of data which is stored in a text file. Essentially, the application browses a .txt file, once located, the application needs to put all the data in the file into a JTable, I need to then perform some filtering operations on the data and then export it out. 
The data present in the .txt file is in this format:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 .........(there are 510 columns)
A       B       C       D       E       F 
G       H       I       J       K       L
....   ...     ...     ...    ....     ...
```

With thousands of rows. Each row consists of double type numbers (A, B....are all 1.3, 2.0, etc)

I've set the columns of the table by manually adding all the column names in an array and then setting the model of the table as

```
table = new JTable();
table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(null,columns)); 
//'columns' is a string array containing 510 names
```

I have put the rows as 'null' here since I have no idea how I should get that data and convert it in a 2D array since that's the format of the rows. Also, there may be ANY number of rows. The code for how I am reading a text file is as follows:

```
    btnBrowse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {                       
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

            int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(dpaGUI.this);               
            if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
            {
              file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
              BufferedReader in = null;
            try 
            {
                in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

              try 
              {
                while(in.ready())
                  {
                    //test operations performed with the retrieved text
                  }
            } 
              catch (IOException e) 
            {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
              try 
              {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        }
    });
```

I tried to perform some test operations like splitting the retrieved text with "\t" (that's how it is meant to be stored in the text file) but no help so far. The text file also contains the name of the columns, so they would need to be deleted when the rows are being filled up. Any suggestions would help, as to how I can get the massive data from my text file into the JTable. I'm using JTable since I need to perform further operations on entire columns of data (each with thousands of rows). I'm open to suggestions for a different container. 
Any suggestions would help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How about pagination? Then you can limit the amount of rows in each page. Another option is to make the user filter before trigger the JTable population.

Comment: Cannot make the user use the filter before, since the user needs to look at the data in the table and THEN select particular columns to apply the filter to.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try. Instead of setting the data to null, you can use the constructor that takes in the column names, and number of rows. Set the rows to 0, and just use `addRow`

```
DefaultTableModel(Object[] cols, int rows)
```

See more method and constructors at [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) api.

Using your particular code, you can use my method to create a `DefaultTableModel` and the use `table.setModel(model)` in your `ActionListener`

**File**

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 
A       B       C       D       E       F 
G       H       I       J       K       L
A       B       C       D       E       F 
G       H       I       J       K       L
A       B       C       D       E       F 
G       H       I       J       K       L
A       B       C       D       E       F 
G       H       I       J       K       L
A       B       C       D       E       F 
G       H       I       J       K       L
A       B       C       D       E       F 
G       H       I       J       K       L
```

**Result**

[image]

**Code**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTable5 {

    public TestTable5() {
        DefaultTableModel model = createModel("/resources/file.txt");
        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private DefaultTableModel createModel(String filePath) {
        DefaultTableModel model = null;

        try {
            BufferedReader txtReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(filePath)));
            String header = txtReader.readLine();
            model = new DefaultTableModel(header.split("\\s+"), 0);
            String line;
            while((line = txtReader.readLine()) != null) {
                model.addRow(line.split("\\s+"));
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return model;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestTable5();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

### UPDATE

You can try this out for using with a `JFileChooser`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTable5 {

    public TestTable5() {
        String[] defaultCols = {"COL", "COL", "COL", "COL", "COL", "COL"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(defaultCols, 0);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        JButton button = createButton(table);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JButton createButton(final JTable table) {
        JButton button = new JButton("Get File");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(table);
                if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                    DefaultTableModel model = createModel(file);
                    table.setModel(model);
                }
            }
        });
        return button;
    }

    private DefaultTableModel createModel(File file) {
        DefaultTableModel model = null;

        try {
            BufferedReader txtReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader(file));
            String header = txtReader.readLine();
            model = new DefaultTableModel(header.split("\\s+"), 0);
            String line;
            while ((line = txtReader.readLine()) != null) {
                model.addRow(line.split("\\s+"));
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return model;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestTable5();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: See my **UDPATE** you can just use my method that returns a `DefaultTableModel`. From you listener, after you get the file from the  file chooser, just pass the file to the method and then set the model of the table, `table.setModel(model)`. Look at the `ActionListener` in the `creatButton` method.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I'll try and play with it. Will post if I have troubles. Thanks a LOT!

Comment: When I import my file (which has 510 columns), the number of rows displayed is correct, but the columns decrease to 5 once the file is loaded :/

Comment: 510 columns are not going to be visible, _ever_ on a normal monitor. So you have to make a decision on you want the data to be viewed.

Comment: No, I meant the count the table columns after importing the file were reduced. I had irregularities in the file, that's why it was showing this behavior, I fixed that and the code worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you think the data set is too large, try to implement your own cell model, deriving from [AbstractTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) instead. The power of the model-oriented approach is exactly that only the total row count and the cells that are currently visible on the screen will be requested from the model. Hence the numbers of rows can be more than computer memory can hold. It may be good idea to employ the database engine as the backend.

Comment: The data I have (for rows that is) in the file, I will need to get it to a 2D string array (String [] []) to add to the abstract data model. I dont know how to get the data from the file and convert it to a 2D array, any suggestions/helpful links?

Comment: If amount of data for each row in the file is fixed (does not matter, plain text or binary data), or it is possible to do so, try with RandomAccessFile.